# How to get all data associate with serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get all the data associated with this `interest_category` serializer. This is what I am currently getting:

```
{
        "project_title": "Dogs",
        "project_description": "and cats",
        "interest_category": [
            4,
            7
        ],
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z"
    },
```

What I am trying to get:

```
{
        "project_title": "Dogs",
        "project_description": "and cats",
        "interest_category": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "interest_name": "Test"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "interest_name": "Business"
            }
        ],
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z"
    },
```

The issue I am having is if I use the below code, I cannot get the `interest_category` "interest_name" and only have the IDs displayed in a GET request:

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('id', 'interest_name')


class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        project_category = validated_data.pop("interest_category", None)
        project_create = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if project_category:
            project_create.interest_category.set(project_category)

        return project_create
```

I have tried using this to GET the data and I can, however when I use this code, I cannot write and set the `interest_category`, it will just be blank:

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('id', 'interest_name')


class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = InterestSerializer(
        many=True, read_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        project_category = validated_data.pop("interest_category", None)
        project_create = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if project_category:
            project_create.interest_category.set(project_category)

        return project_create
```

If I use one or the other, I cannot POST the `interest_category` or I cannot GET the `interest_category`. How can I make it so I can get the data that I need to GET and POST the request with the same serializer. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the **to_representation()** method or inherit InterestSerializer in ProjectsSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

The change that I made is on ProjectsSerializers and Project's views

```
# The Base of ProjectsSerializers
class BaseProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        project_category = validated_data.pop("interest_category", None)
        project_create = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if project_category:
            project_create.interest_category.set(project_category)

        return project_create

class WriteProjectsSerializer(BaseProjectsSerializer):  # <<<< -------- HERE
    interest_category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True
    )


class ReadProjectsSerializer(BaseProjectsSerializer):   # <<<< -------- HERE
    interest_category = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    def get_interest_category(self, instance):
        interest_category = instance.interest_category.all()
        serializer = InterestSerializer(instance=interest_category, many=True)
        return serializer.data

# In your View, add a dict of serializer_classes and set a default serializer
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Project Viewset"""
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    default_serializer_class = ReadProjectsSerializer # < --------- HERE
    serializer_classes = {  # < ---------------------------------- HERE
        'create': WriteProjectsSerializer,
        'update': WriteProjectsSerializer,
        'partial_update': WriteProjectsSerializer,
    }
```

Comment: So I tried this and I am only passing the Id or pk for interest_category. How can I pass the interest_name from the InterestSerializer to get the name of the category to display on frontend?

Comment: This is the data I am getting:

{
        "project_title": "test",
        "project_description": "test",
        "interest_category": [
            3,
            4,
            5
        ],
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-09-17T03:32:41.795586Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-17T03:32:41.795586Z"
    }

Comment: Maybe the StringRelatedField will work. Suggested by @sajeyks-mwangi

Answer (score 0):

I think now I understand what you are trying to do. You want to create a writable nested serializer. Try this:

```py
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('id', 'interest_name')


class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = InterestSerializer(many=True)# new

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]

    # new edits
    def create(self, validated_data):
        interests_data = validated_data.pop("interest_category")
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for interest_data in interests_data:
            Interests.objects.create(project=project, **interest_data)

        return project
```

This can get you:

```
{
        "project_title": "Dogs",
        "project_description": "and cats",
        "interest_category": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "interest_name": "Test"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "interest_name": "Business"
            }
        ],
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-17T04:31:40.884357Z"
    },
```

You can read more [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Comment: I tried this. I am just getting the interest_name, not the ID.

Comment: I improved it to create a writable nested serializer. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

#### It can be solved using context data and read_only options.

views.py

```
...

ProjectsSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request}
```

serializers.py

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('id', 'interest_name')

class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = InterestSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'interest_category',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        interest_category = self.context['request'].data.get("interest_category", None)
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if interest_category:
            interests = Interests.objects.filter(id__in=interest_category)
            project_create.interest_category.set(interests)

        return project
```